# I use mkdir in Perl. It makes dir, but sometimes it adds a ? to the end of the directory name

Tags: perl, directory, mkdir

Here is the code:

```
foreach my $name ( @unique_gene_list ) {
    print "$name\n";
    chomp $name; 

    unless(mkdir $name, 0700) {
        die "Unable to create directory called $name\n";
    }
}
```

This works, mostly. For some reason, one of my directories is given a name that ends with a ?. I should note that the directory name showing in the terminal window shows the question mark. In the finder, there is no question mark at the end of that directory's name. I use Perl v.5.12.3, on a MAc OS 10.7.5.

Comment: Try to print the `ord` of the last char of the name: `print ord substr $name, -1`

Comment: Also you can try to pass it though cat: `ls -l | cat -vet`. -vet prints almost all weird characters that are otherwise invisible

Comment: I don't understand, @choroba. ? Do you mean that the result will be diagnostic for something? I'll try it.

Comment: @ES55 - your "?" is probably some weird unprintable character that was part of some names in the list. Unix shell would print it as "?"

Comment: @DVK: Big thanks for introducing me to `cat -vet` - very useful!

Comment: @DVK, I used `ls -l | cat -vet`. All the directories are shown to end with a `$`, even my weird directory with the mystery ?. But for that particular one, there is an ^M before the $ and in place of the ?. So, it was an end line character causing the ?. I find that weird, though, since i was chomping things at multiple places.

Comment: See Ikegami's answer. ^M is a Carriage Return, and ^M$ means the string has DOS format newline, not Unix format newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file from which you are reading has lines ending in CRLF. You are removing the LF with `chomp`, but the CR (represented by ^M) isn't removed. Instead of `chomp;`, use `s/\s+\z//;`.

```
while (<$fh>) {
   s/\s+\z//;
   ...
}
```